# How to get value of checkbox onchange without id or class using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I wants to alert checkbox value if selected.And it will not have any **id or class**. It's a listbox item which is having checkbox. User may select multiple checkbox.

Here is my **ASPX code**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListStoreID" CssClass="multiselect" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ID" DataValueField="ID">

</asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:datareload33 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [Store] WHERE ([Inactive] = @Inactive)">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="Inactive" Type="Boolean" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_ListStoreID]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            buttonText: function (options, select) {
                return 'StoreID';
            },
            buttonTitle: function (options, select) {
                var labels = [];
                options.each(function () {
                    labels.push($(this).text());
                });
                return labels.join(' - ');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

> I am using **SQLDataSource** to bring the list from database. So It will not have any id or class.

**screanshot**

[image: screenshot of aspx code]

[image: client side code]

**Update**

[image: last screenshot]

Comment: Can you post the rendered markup once `.multiselect()` has done its thing please.

Comment: @KristianRoebuck please wait. I will update

Comment: @KristianRoebuck Did you see my update?

Answer (score 1):

You can select a group of items just by its node type. Take a look at the next snippet, the selector selects all the inputs inside the element with the class `multiselect-container`. Then you can add a "change" event to that selection.

```js
var checkboxes = $(".multiselect-container input");

checkboxes.on("change", function() {

  console.log($(this).val() + " --> " + $(this).prop("checked"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1001" />1001
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="1">
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1201" />1201
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="2">
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="2001" />2001
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="3">
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="2200" />2200
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="4">
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1004" />1004
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

As you are using a `jQuery` plugin to create the `checkboxes`, it is better to use the `jQuery` built-in event delegation to create the "change" event. Something like this:

```
var container = $(".multiselect-container");

container.on("change", "input", function() {

  console.log($(this).val() + " --> " + $(this).prop("checked"));

});
```

Comment: @ElchinNet I know your code should work. But for me I don't know why it's not working

Comment: @ElchinNet is it not alerting due it creates at runtime?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz Maybe you are adding the event and the checkboxes don't exist in that moment. Try to use `event delegation`. Look at my edition.

Comment: Also in your case you need to use the `[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_ListStoreID]` selector instead `.multiselect-container`.

Comment: can you please update your code with your code `[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_ListStoreID]`

Comment: when I add your code in console directly, it's giving output what we expect. But when I put your code on js file. It's not responding. I check link in the header file, remove the history in browser. I checked with multiple browser. No response

Comment: can you check my last update?.  the list is showing two times on the client side

Comment: @mohamedfaiz, just replace `.multiselect-container` by `[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_ListStoreID]`, it should work. I don't understand your last update.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can bind events to either element types or a collection of element child.
I would try the following

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked){
            //alert whatever you need.. probably this.value
            alert(this.value); 
    }
});
```

Comment: change it to .click

Answer (score 0):

For this **Bootstrap-multiselect jquery add on**, there is a specific function to get the selected values.

**Here is the code:**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListStoreID" CssClass="multiselect records" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ID" DataValueField="ID">                    
</asp:ListBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recordsf1534 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [Store] WHERE ([Inactive] = @Inactive)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="Inactive" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_ListStoreID]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            buttonText: function (options, select) {
                return 'StoreID';
            },
            buttonTitle: function (options, select) {
                var labels = [];
                options.each(function () {
                    labels.push($(this).text());
                });                  
                alert(labels.join(','));   // this alert will bring whenever user select the checkbox
                return labels.join(' , ');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation of that `jQuery` plugin, the correct option to get the *checkbox value if selected* is the [onChange](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange) option. The [buttonTitle](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-buttonTitle) option is not *a specific function to get the selected values*, it is an option to set the title of the button depending on the values selected and it receives all the selected options as a parameter (the same happens with the **buttonText** option)